# grep always exits with 0 exit status in if statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I want to write a bash script that simulates Korn cd command: `cd old new`
which substitutes `old` with `new` in PWD and then tries to `cd` to the new directory.

here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function korn_cd
{
  case "$#" in
    0 | 1 ) builtin cd $1 ;;
    2     )  if ! echo "$PWD" | grep "$old" ; then
              echo "bash: cd: bad subsitiution";
              return 1;
            fi;

            new_dir=${PWD//$1/$2};
            builtin cd $new_dir; ;;
    *    ) echo "bash: cd: wrong arg count" 1>&2; return 1 ;;
  esac ;
}
```

in if condition, `grep` must check if `old` is in `PWD` or not. if it is not in `PWD`, the "bad substitution" error message must be printed. my problem is that the `exit status` of `grep` is always `0`. so the if condition never execute.

exmaple:

```
PWD="~/Documents/Code"
korn_cd aaaaa bbbbb
```

I don't see the error message "bad substitution".

how can I fix it?

Comment: Not what you asked about, but if `$1` is set and contains whitespace, the expansion will break, so it might be a good idea to split out the no arguments case. Or use something like `cd ${1+"$1"}`, which seems to work, but somehow feels a bit iffy to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `old` is never set, at least, not in the part of your code that you have posted.  `grep` will always match when searching for a null string `""`, and return a zero exit code:

```
$ echo $PWD | grep ""; echo $?
/home/jim
0
```

Comment: amazing! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient to use a string comparison in `bash`:

```
if [[ $PWD != *$old* ]]; then
```

assuming `$old` has some value (it's not set in your function, which is your issue).

I think a partial implementation of your function could look like

```bash
cd () {
    if [[ $PWD != *$1* ]]; then
        printf 'cd: string not in pwd: %s\n' "$1"
        return 1
    fi
    builtin cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"
}
```

(borrowing the error message from `zsh` which has the same `cd` feature built in)

This function would not allow the user to pass any other arguments to `cd` though. To handle options, you would have to do full command line parsing.

Ignoring options:

```bash
cd () {
    if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
        builtin cd "$@"
        return
    fi

    if [[ $PWD != *$1* ]]; then
        printf 'cd: string not in pwd: %s\n' "$1"
        return 1
    fi
    builtin cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"
}
```

Comment: `! echo foo | grep` should be fine, the `!` inverts the exit status of the whole pipeline. ([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02)). That said, `echo foo | ! grep` is a syntax error in Bash, Dash, and Zsh  (but not in my ksh or mksh)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the reality check.

Comment: You're quite welcome. The bang just looked odd there so I had to check...